# How to replace all characters in a string in Dart except the space character

Tags: string, dart, replaceall

```
String text = "replace all characters" --> 22 characters

text.replaceAll(RegExp('.'), '*');   

// result -> ********************** --> 22 characters
```

In this way, all characters change. How do I exclude the space character.

```
// I want it this

// result -> ******* *** ********** -> Characters 8 and 13 are empty.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a negative match:

```
void main() {
  String text = "replace all characters";
  print(text.replaceAll(RegExp('[^ ]'), '*'));
  // ******* *** **********
}
```

`[^ ]`Will match any character that is not space.